# redirect to a certain page on back click

Tags: javascript, php

i was working on an onlnie exam system using php and mysql, while the user is taking the exam he should not be able to leave with back button, and i faced a problem with that. I found a code which brings an alert message when the back button or the reload button are pressed, the alert message asks the user:"do you want to leave?" and the user either clicks on "stay on page" or "leave page" option. If the user clicks "leave page" he gets redirected to the previous page, **but what I want is for the user to be redirected to the result  page when he click the "leave page" option instead of being redirected to the  previous page.** This is the javascript code that I used:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = "Are You sure.",
  e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
  }

};

</script>
```

I am new to the php language so it would helpful if someone can solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: here what to do with php?

Comment: working on online exam system and this problem occurred when taking the exam. I want the student to be directed to the result page if clicks the back button and chooses to leave the exam

Answer (score 3):

Use the `history api` to manipulate browser history. More information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API